# Page Speed testing timers

Tags: json, browser, speed-test

Im currently working on an integration where the external service returns json strings.

Some of the strings are quite long, and im just wondering if anyone knows of a plugin that can be used to count down how long a total request takes.

I know i could run a timer on the server to monitor how long the request takes, but what im hoping to see is if there is a way to time the entire experience within a browser so I can see how long it takes to request content and display the end result (the webpage) to a user ?

thanks in advance

Comment: The built in Google Chrome developer tools and/or the Firefox Development tools will gladly do this for you. Heck, even the IE11 tools will show you this information. All you have to do is look.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you can use the Network tab of Developer Tools to see the timeline, from which you can check the request times and data size of any requested resource within the lifetime of your page.

[image: developer tools]

Alternatively, if what you mean is that you need to have access to the time from within your code, you can measure the time between issuing the request and receiving the response. Something like this should suffice.

```
var start = Date.now();
http.request(resourceUrl, function(data) {
  var stop, duration;
  stop = Date.now();
  duration = stop - start;
  // duration of request in ms
  doSomething(data);
});
```